# Dropdown not show in the correct place

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

im try write a navbar with two dropdowns. My code:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Informes <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="#">Platos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Grilla</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

The dropdown is visible, but not in the correct place. Example:

[image]

Any ideas ?.

Comment: Without giving us more code I can't even say if you're using js or jquery or pure css for your nav! how should I get what is your problem? a jsfiddle sample is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Lacked of ul tag closing, maybe.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Informes <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="#">Platos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Grilla</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```